# Show accelerator key in menu

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I am using Gtkmm 3.22.30 on Ubuntu and I have been trying to show accelerator keys in my application menu, without success. So far, I have been able to register an accelerator key to my menu items, but for some reason, they don't appear in my menu. I know this is possible, because I have seen it in Inkscape, which I believe is using Gtkmm as well (For example: New is bound to `<Control>N`:

[image: Inkscape]

I have prepared a minimal example to show my problem (and what I have done). Here is the code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::ApplicationWindow
{

public:

    MainWindow();

private:

    void OnActivateSubItem()
    {
        std::cout << "Handler called" << std::endl;
    }
    
    Gtk::MenuBar  m_menuBar;
    Gtk::MenuItem m_mainMenu{"Menu"};
    Gtk::Menu     m_menu;
    Gtk::MenuItem m_subItem{"Item"};  // Menu|Item
 
};

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    // Setting the menu up:
    add(m_menuBar);

    m_menuBar.append(m_mainMenu);
    m_mainMenu.set_submenu(m_menu);
    m_menu.append(m_subItem);

    // Adding accelerator:
    auto accel_group = Gtk::AccelGroup::create();
    add_accel_group(accel_group);
    m_menu.set_accel_group(accel_group);

    // I would have believed this to do the trick but, meh...
    m_subItem.add_accelerator("activate",
                              accel_group,
                              GDK_KEY_y,
                              Gdk::ModifierType::CONTROL_MASK,
                              Gtk::ACCEL_VISIBLE);

    m_subItem.signal_activate().connect([this]{OnActivateSubItem();});
}

int main()
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create("my.menu.problem");

    MainWindow window;
    window.show_all();

    return app->run(window);
}
```

which leads to the following:

[image]

I was expecting a `Ctrl + y` entry next to the `Item` menu item (especially with the `Gtk::ACCEL_VISIBLE` flag for which I have found no documentation), but nothing is showing except a blank space. When I hit `Ctrl + y`, "Handler called" appears in the console, so the accelerator works.

I have look through the API but it is very confusing and badly documented (I was not able to find a working example for Gtkmm 3.22.30, not even in the examples coming with the source code).

How can I achieve this?

Notes:

1. I am looking for an answer which does not involve `Gtk::Builder` if possible.
2. The answer can use C code if what I want to do is not possible in Gtkmm, but I would need it to integrate with my Gtkmm code.

Comment: accelerator keys. That's a new one. Any different from hotkey? Not trying for sarcasm here. I really do want to know if they're the same thing.

Comment: I think they are the same. From the [Gtkmm documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1AccelKey.html#details): "For instance, pressing Control-Q to activate the File|Quit menu item."

Comment: Thanks. Man, I hope nobody has a patent or trademark for hotkey.

Comment: There are many ways to do it, but I think that the simplest one would be [GtkAccelLabel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBBrMBy-hn0&list=PLN_MPJUQgPVqXVqY37Ry-OQQf-3Oy7Dfw). Any way if it is only about actions with MENUs, then probably [This is what you need](https://youtu.be/b7ctDMeohug)

Comment: I would need something with the C++ bindings (Gtkmm). Some GTK functions do not seem to have an equivalent in Gtkmm. For example, how do you add a `GtkAccelLabel` to a `MenuItem`? In GTK, there seems to be the call `gtk_menu_item_new_with_label()` to do the job, but I have found no equivalent call in GTKmm.

Comment: You should use GMenu and not GtkMenu.

Comment: What is your Gtkmm version ? 3.0 or 4.0 ? Because i just tried your example on my machine, and its correctly displaying Ctrl+Y in the menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```cpp
> add_accel_group(accel_group);
> m_menu.set_accel_group(accel_group);
> ```

I think the same AccelGroup cannot be assigned to a window **and** a menu. I searched the docs for details on this and found nothing, but my tummy feeling says me you have to delete one of these lines. And in [this example](https://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/menusandtoolbars/) they use the AccelGroup only in the window, too. I suggest to delete the second line.

**EDIT**: i think you are using a different Gtkmm version than i am, because the code you provided works fine on my machine. Could you please compile following c++ program, run it and post its output ?

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    cout << gtk_get_major_version() << "." << gtk_get_minor_version() << "." << gtk_get_micro_version();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to check. I'll compile and run this tonight and let you know.

Comment: @BobMorane No problem !

Comment: Printed version is `3.22.30`

Comment: @BobMorane ok, mine is 3.24.24, so it may be a bug. Did you try to remove one of the lines i mentioned ?

Comment: Yes I tried. If I remove `add_accel_group(accel_group);`, the accelerator no longer works... I am also starting to believe this is a bug. out of curiosity, are you running Ubuntu?

Comment: @BobMorane yes i have Ubuntu 18.04, and I installed Gtkmm using JHbuild ... Try removing `m_menu.set_accel_group(accel_group);`; it doesn't make sense to me to first add the accel group to the main window, and then setting the same one onto the menu bar !

Comment: Ok, I tried it. You were right: it was useless. The program works just as before without it. However, the accelerator is still not displayed :( When I find time, I will try to upgrade my Gtkmm to see if it does the trick.

Comment: @BobMorane i wanted to try and downgrade __my__ Gtkmm to 3.22.30, but it is __not possible__ with JHbuild ...

Comment: @BobMorane you can only __upgrade__ with JHbuild ...

Comment: Oh... good to know. I will try in a VM then. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BobMorane no what i  meant is, you can only install the newest version of a module in JHbuild, not a newer (okay, this is impossible), and not an older one. Only if you have an older version than the newest, you can _upgrade_.

Comment: @BobMorane but you should use a VM all the same, to not break your current environment.

Comment: Just tried building `3.24.24` with jhbuild... What a mess lol. I am stuck with the following error when building `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libxml2'`. I tried every way I could think of of installing this, but nothing seems to work. As usual, the jhbuild documentation is next to inexistant...

Comment: This is during the install of `yelp-xsl`.

Comment: yeah, the docs of JHbuild are ****, but I think this can be fixed `apt install python-libxml2` (supposing you are using Linux)

Comment: Maybe the [installation instructions](http://www.xmlsoft.org/FAQ.html#Installati) can help you ...

Comment: Just tested on Ubuntu 20.10, which uses Gtkmm 3.24 and my code works as expected. @Programmer, many thanks for your testing, your comments on my code and your support.

Comment: @BobMorane no problem, you helped me too !